# Cannot map query string array to object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string, datatables

I am using server side processing with JQuery DataTables and I'm trying to map part of the query string request to an object in my action. This query string request comes from an AJAX call that's handled by datatables

The query string parameters look like this for the first column in the request (decoded):

```
order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:asc
```

In my controller I have this action:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonNetResult Employees(int start, int length, int draw, Sort[] order)
```

I have a sort class that looks like this:

```
public class Sort
{
    public int column { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
}
```

The order array is populated when a request is made and it shows that it has 1 item in the collection. However the column property is always 0 and dir is always null. What am I missing so that these fields get populated?

**EDIT**

I can easily do this to retrieve the value that I like:

```
var result = Request.QueryString["order[0][dir]"];
```

However I'm looking to model bind this if it's possible?

Comment: How do you create this query? Could you show the view's code please

Comment: I've updated my original post. The calls comes from an AJAX request so there is very little view code to show. Still I can provide the JavaScript initialisation code if you like?

Answer (score 0):

If you using mvc, try replace this approach for this:

OLD

```
public JsonNetResult Employees(int start, int length, int draw, Sort[] order)
```

NEW

```
public JsonNetResult Employees(formCollection form)
{
  Employees e = new Employees();
  TryUpdateModel<Employees>(e, form);

}
```

Comment: I should probably have explained this comes from an AJAX call which is handled in jquery datatables

Answer (score 0):

works for me, i using this code:

**Class ViewModel**

```
public class DocumentViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int EmissionDate { get; set; }
        public int Institute { get; set; }
        public string MaturityDate { get; set; }
    }
```

**Html**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "testform" }))
{
    <input type="text" name="Number" />

    <input type="text" name="EmissionDate" />

    <input type="text" name="MaturityDate" />

    <input type="submit" id="send" value="Enviar" />
}
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#send").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                console.log($("#testform").serialize());

                $.post("@Url.Content("~/Home/About")", $("#testform").serialize())
                .done(function (data) {
                    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Try this code